# Length of Day and year on massive Earth

Tags: general-relativity, time-dilation

Say, a planet has the same orbital periods as Earth (365 days in a year, 24 hours in a day, etc. with respect to Earth-bound clocks), but the planet has double the mass. So, time must pass more slowly on that planet compared to Earth, right? What would it feel like to live on that planet? What would be the length of day and year according to their clock?

Comment: Maybe try http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Philosophically, you can’t notice whether a (dimensional) physical quantity became “greater” or “less” in a new, altered world. These are **numbers** that can be “greater” or “less”, **not quantities in different worlds,** where you can’t put two quantities side-by-side and look on both of them simultaneously. Please, clarify what does “the clock tick faster or slower” mean in practice. Which devices do you propose to evaluate (as clocks) and with respect to which reference process? For example, you can suppose two planets in the same system with a communication channel between them.

Comment: @Incnis He must be asking number about number of hours in a day and number of days in a year there. That's why he involved same orbital period.

Comment: This is a very good question...

Answer (score 1):

`If acceleration is equivalent to gravitation, it follows that the predictions of Special Relativity must also be valid for very strong gravitational fields. The curvature of spacetime by matter therefore not only stretches or shrinks distances, depending on their direction with respect to the gravitational field, but also appears to slow down the flow of time. This effect is called gravitational time dilation. In most circumstances, such gravitational time dilation is minuscule and hardly observable, but it can become very significant when spacetime is curved by a massive object, such as a black hole.`

To be more explicit even you were able to approach a black hole your clock would appear to work normally. The time-dilation would happen in respect to an observer away from the black hole. So on the made up planet time would also feel like flowing normally.

If, however you are wondering about the time-dilation that is caused by a body with 1,5 times the mass of earth then i have to say that it would be negligible, since its mass would be still small.

Answer (score 1):

> Say a planet has the same orbital period as Earth (365 days in a year, 24 hours in a day, etc.) but the planet has double the mass.

For an even more direct comparison let's say that the latter planet has double the (average) density of planet Earth, so the surfaces of both have (as good as) equal circumference; and let's say that the durations of orbital periods of both planets are exactly equal, as determined by some suitable common non-rotating reference system.

> [...] Would the clock tick faster or slower or the same?

It's not sensible to ask this about only one clock, "*the clock*".

What we can ask, and (in experimental physics) we routinely do ask, is:
Considering **two clocks**, either directly next to each other, or separated from each other (e.g. even on two different planets) which of them was "*ticking faster*" **in comparison**; or were they "ticking at equal rates"?

Of course it's easy to compare two clocks which are kept "right next to each other". Your question is apparently concerned with the more difficult case of comparing (the rates of) two separate clocks, but the described setup is suggesting some simplifying approximations:

- the two surfaces with the two clocks are (as good as) at equal "radial height $R$",
- this radial surface heigh $R$ at which the two clocks are held (separately) was relatively large, i.e. much larger than $\frac{G~M_E}{c^2}$, where $M_E$ is the mass of Earth, and
- the speeds of these two clocks with respect to some suitable common non-rotating reference system were relatively small, i.e. much smaller than $\frac{G~M_E~c^2}{R}$.

Consequently, if one clock (moving with the Earth's surface) counted $n^{\text{orbit}}_E$ ticks within one full orbit,
and the other clock (moving with the surface of the other, denser planet $P$) counted $n^{\text{orbit}}_P$ ticks within one full orbit, and if the ratio between these two tick counts was equal to

$$\frac{n^{\text{orbit}}_P}{n^{\text{orbit}}_E} = \frac{1 - \frac{G~M_P}{R~c^2}}{1 - \frac{G~M_E}{R~c^2}} = \frac{1 - \frac{G~2M_E}{R~c^2}}{1 - \frac{G~M_E}{R~c^2}} = 2 - \frac{1}{1 - \frac{G~M_E}{R~c^2}} \approx 1 - \frac{G~M_E}{R~c^2},$$

then these two clocks were ticking at (as good as) equal rates, at least on average.